# Does linking to external video sources use my server bandwidth and resources?

Tags: hosting, youtube, web-hosting

If I include a link on a webpage to a YouTube (or externally hosted video source), does that video file utilize my server's bandwidth and resources (cpu, memory, etc) or is it a direct client to external host connection?

We have started to think about including training files for our internal employees that we would likely host externally but did not know how this would affect existing performance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  The browser instead uses the link to connect to YouTube's server, and uses their resources.